# cPanel cron jobs email error

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I am receiving an error email shoing that something wrong is going with the cron jobs and php

this is the error:

```
Can't locate Umask/Local.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/cpanel /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl . /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Mkdir.pm line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Mkdir.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/CustInfo/Save.pm line 24.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/CustInfo/Save.pm line 24.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/ContactInfo/Sync.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/ContactInfo/Sync.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/ContactInfo.pm line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/ContactInfo.pm line 16.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/QuickInstall.pm line 25.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/QuickInstall.pm line 25.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/quickinstall/scripts/checkupdates.pl line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/quickinstall/scripts/checkupdates.pl line 8.
```

I believe this happened when I upgraded the php into 5.6

cron joob that I have in cPanel are:

```
57  1   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/perl /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/quickinstall/scripts/checkupdates.pl
30  *   *   *   *   /opt/php56/bin/php-cgi -q /home/[username]/public_html/backup/cron.php
5   *   *   *   *   /opt/php56/bin/php-cgi -q /home/[username]/public_html/order/crons/cron.php
```

any help? and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Login to WHM, go to Software -> Install a perl module. There you can type thise module Umask::Local and see if any results are returned.

Alternatively you can do a yum search Umask and manually install that package. The package name should be something like:

```
cpanel-perl-522-Umask-Local.x86_64
```

Of course it might be different in your case (it depends on the OS CentOS 6.x or 7.x and cPanel/WHM version).

That should fix it for you.